# Extracting a field from a line with condition in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I am reading lines from a file and need to extract field 3 from lines in another file if fields 5 and 6 from the first file exist in the second file.

I tried to do so with the following but it doesn't work. I appreciate any help.

```
filename=file.txt
while read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5
do
     awk '$17 == $f4 && $18 == $f5 {print $3}' file2.txt

done < "$filename"
```

Comment: can you post contents of both the files?

Comment: Probably, it doesn't work because you've mixed shell variables with awk variables. Try this: `awk -v f4="$f4" -v f5="$f5" '$17 == f4 && $18 == f5 {print $3}' file2.txt`

Comment: Lose the shell loop, it's not needed and is the wrong approach. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do this all in awk, using getline()

```
awk '{var1=$5; var2=$6
  while ((getline < "file2.txt") > 0)
     if (index($0, var1) && index($0, var2)) print $3
  close("file2.txt")
}' file1.txt
```

You are reading each line from file1.txt, putting field 5 & 6 into an awk variable to test later.  Then using a while/getline to go through each line of the second file, and if both fields are found, then printing $3.  Closing the file so that the next loop starts from record 1 of the second file.

Or, if you want to have a bash loop in file1, and then use awk, you can pass the variables in (as mentioned here by someone else), or escape them out.

`awk '{if ($2 == '$var1') print $3}' file2.txt`

The above will see the bash variable $var1 as a string in awk.

Comment: The first script is the wrong approach, see http://awk.info/?tip/getline, and so is the second - never let shell variables expand as part of the body of an awk script like that, see http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24.

Comment: There is no ill effects from using getline in a awk script of this size.  It's too simple to worry about it.

Comment: Instead of reading file2 once your script will read the whole of file2 once for every line in file1, so if file1 contains 1,000 lines your script will read the whole of file2 1,000 times instead of just reading it once. It also does partial matching across the whole of each line instead of precisely matching the whole of specific fields and so will produce false matches given many possible input values. You can, of course, choose not to worry about those things if you like but I highly recommend that the OP at least consider them.

Comment: I have no problem with another way of doing things, but I standby my opinion that the statement "this is wrong" is gainsay and elitist.  For the scope of what is being doing, clarity is more important than extra read. Read calls are quick, they aren't a write to disk.  Doing something "right" but not knowing what you are doing (I doubt the OP would grok what you wrote with no explanations) is also "wrong".

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach will be something like:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { a[$17,$18]=$3; next }
($4,$5) in a { print a[$4,$5] }
' file2.txt file.txt
```

but it's an untested guess since you haven't provided sample input/output yet.

Comment: This is incredibly confusing.  If SO is going to start down voting styles they don't like, b/c it doesn't work in certain situations-- for the love of God teach readability and style.

Comment: Also, you should explain to the OP what you are doing, so he/she can learn and not use SO for ever issue.

Comment: @SaintHax if the OP has any questions then of course they are welcome to ask but this is **THE** idiomatic awk solution to this problem, described countless times in various web sites, books, and forums. If anyone doesn't understand this then there is a lot more they need to learn before starting to use awk. I recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: awk, sed, bash are quick [to write], uncompiled languages that fill a purpose for quick and dirty solutions.  By their nature they are available to people who are not masters of them.  They support indentations and comments like every other language, which is just as important, if not more, than the objections you have raised.  There is no reason to expect someone to read anything other than a man page, and no reason to not comment on awk functions that are alien to the way most languages do things.  It's picky and choosing to do otherwise.

Comment: When you write object oriented C++ code do you write it as if it was Pascal and comment the differences for the benefit of those who don't understand the fundamentals of OO/C++? Of course not so why would you expect idiomatic awk code to be commented for the benefit of those who don't understand the fundamentals of awk? You are projecting your own limited experience, needs and beliefs onto the community as a whole. YOU think of shell as quick and dirty, YOU think reading a man page should be adequate, and YOU think there is such a thing as "most languages" we all should code in the style of.

Comment: C++ is an OOP language, that needs to be compiled, and is not just added to the Unix tool set to solve problem.  I expect someone using a CNC machine needs training, a Dremel tool to fix a rough edge on his home furniture not so much.  Also, the comment is not b/c of my experience, not my limitations.  I've had my code handed over to other people, I've had to enhance a project that's sat idle and forgotten-- I know the value of comments.  I also can infer the limitations of the OP, who had no way of solving this.  YOU... are wrong and defensive.

Comment: btw, what other languages let you use `a' like you did with no explicit assignment or declaration?  Since it's only ME that thinks most languages don't.

Comment: Y'know what - you're absolutely right, it's me, thank you for the education. Please do continue to use awk and every other tool/language as if it were C or whatever language it is you have in mind as representing "most languages".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110494/discussion-between-sainthax-and-ed-morton).